# Remove the number of hard links from the output of `ls -al` command

Tags: bash, ls

Here is outpu of `ls -al` command:

```
total 280K
drwxrwxr-x 2 enan enan 4.0K Jun 28 09:59 ranger/
drwxrwxr-x 2 enan enan 4.0K Jun  8 23:26 scripts/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan   49 Jun  4 18:19 caps_to_ctrl.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan  739 Jun  4 18:19 cmus.theme
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 8.6K Jun  4 18:19 compton.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 5.9K Jun 22 09:39 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan  859 Jun 14 12:13 i3blocks.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 4.7K Jun 14 12:13 init.el
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 8.7K Jun 28 11:22 init.vim
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan  815 Jun 14 12:13 install.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 enan enan  142 Jun  4 18:19 lock.sh*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 1.1K Jun 21 13:30 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 197K Jun 14 12:13 screenshot.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan 1.2K Jun 20 21:51 Session.vim
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enan enan  427 Jun  9 13:46 tmux.sh
```

You can see there is a number between the file permissions `-rw-rw-r--` and file owner `enan`. That number is the number of hard links of the file. Showing that in the output might be useful for some cases but right now, I don't need it and it distracts me sometimes. You can see, I had a way to remove the last modified date from the output of `ls -al` because I don't need it right now.

So, how can I remove the number of hard links from the output of `ls -al` command? And what is the importance of having the number of hard links and last modified date being shown in the output of the command? I mean, if any of you use those info, tell me why and how you do so, cause I don't wanna unintentionally shadow a behavior that I should use.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: @muru Sorry, I didn't think of that. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to see the links which are in the second column then you can pipe `ls -al` into `awk` to remove it:

```
ls -al | awk '{$2=""; print $0}'
```

That will print all but the second column using the standard delimiter in this case which is a space.

In my environment, the columns for the last modified date are 6, 7, and 8 using space as the delimiter so to get rid of them and the second column:

```
ls -la | awk '{$2=$6=$7=$8=""; print $0}'
```

If you don't need or want to see some of the columns then you can use the syntax above as a model to remove whichever ones you desire. It's not going to hurt anything. If you just want to see all the columns as not to miss anything then use the standard:

```
ls -al
```

If you want an alias, add the following to ~/.bashrc:

```
la() {
    ls -la | awk '{$2=$6=$7=$8=""; print $0}'
}
```

That's a function that behaves in the same way without having to account for and escape the single and double quotes. I used `la` as `ll` gives a syntax error as it's already an alias in my environment.

Comment: Can you give me an alias for `ll='ls -al | awk <what goes here?>`. I'm having trouble with `'` quotes.

Comment: See my update for a function as an alias.

Comment: I don't see anything. Where is the update?

Comment: @EnanAjmain There it is. `la` is the alias

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the columns get left aligned and the file names get zigzagged. Any suggestion?

Comment: @EnanAjmain I noticed that too but I don't know of a way to change the formatting so that it looks cleaner offhand. You'll have to do some research into it. It looks like it can be done with some further use of `awk` to realign the spacing but it'd get more complicated.

Comment: Okay........................

Answer (score 1):

To remove the hard link count from the output of `ls -l` while still leaving the rest of the line intact:

```
ls -l | sed -E '2,$s/ +[0-9]+//'
```

The `sed` substitution will remove the first set of digits and any space before it on each line after the first line (the first line contains the `total`).

As a function

```
myls () {
    command ls -l "$@" | sed -E '2,$s/ +[0-9]+//'
}
```

This function invokes `ls -l` with any other command line arguments given by the user to the function before sending the result through `sed`.

By using `command ls`, we ensure that, if you later decide to rename the function into `ls`, the function would not call itself recursively.

Example:

```
$ ls -la ~/.skel
total 18
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk    wheel  512 May  4 16:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 kk    wheel  512 Jun 28 08:15 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel   87 Nov  1  2017 .Xdefaults
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel  771 Feb  9 10:18 .cshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel  101 Nov  1  2017 .cvsrc
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel  359 Nov  1  2017 .login
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel  175 Nov  1  2017 .mailrc
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel  229 May  4 16:29 .profile
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel  108 Apr 15 12:50 .vimrc
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel    0 Apr 21 17:44 .zshrc

$ myls -a ~/.skel
total
drwxr-xr-x  kk    wheel  512 May  4 16:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  kk    wheel  512 Jun 28 08:15 ..
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel   87 Nov  1  2017 .Xdefaults
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel  771 Feb  9 10:18 .cshrc
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel  101 Nov  1  2017 .cvsrc
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel  359 Nov  1  2017 .login
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel  175 Nov  1  2017 .mailrc
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel  229 May  4 16:29 .profile
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel  108 Apr 15 12:50 .vimrc
-rw-r--r--  kk    wheel    0 Apr 21 17:44 .zshrc
```

---

A variation of the function that acts *exactly* like `ls` unless you use `ls -l`:

```
ls () (
    add_filter=0
    while getopts ':l' opt; do
        case $opt in
            l)  add_filter=1 ;;
            1)  add_filter=0
        esac
    done

    command ls "$@" | 
    if [ "$add_filter" -eq 1 ]; then
        sed -E '2,$s/ +[0-9]+//'
    else
        cat
    fi
)
```

The function does its own command line parsing to detect whether the `-l` option was used (and also not later disabled through the use of `-1`).  If it was, we set a flag.  Later, if the flag was set, we filter the output of `ls` through `sed`.  If the flag wasn't set, we just pass the output as-is through `cat`.

Comment: The linkcount can be sometimes more than one digit, so you need `s/ +[0-9]+//` plus this clobbers the number in the `total` line so better `2,$s...`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

With ast-open's `ls` (also the builtin `ls` of ksh93 if it has been included and `/opt/ast/bin` is ahead of `/bin` in `$PATH`), you can fully specify the output format and omit the number of links (`%3(nlink)u`) there:

```
ls -rSZ '%(mode)s %-8(uid)s %-8(gid)s %8(device:case::%(size)u:*:%(device)s)s %(atime)s %(name)s%(linkop:case:?*: %(linkop)s %(linkpath)s)s'
```